# Reference count is still 1 after [obj release], when it should be deallocated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, reference-counting, retaincount

When I create an object and check its retain count, I get 1 as expected. When I release the object and then check the retain count again, it is still 1. Shouldn't the object be deallocated, and the retain count 0?

```
NSMutableString *str=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
NSLog(@"reference count is %i",[str retainCount]);
[str release];
NSLog(@"reference count is %i",[str retainCount]);
```

I *do* see 0 for the retain count if I set `str` to `nil` first. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `retainCount`, it doesn't do what you expect in most cases.

Your second `NSLog` is accessing deallocated memory as an object. In this particular case, that deallocated memory still contains enough of the old data from the NSString that was just freed for the program to not crash when the `retainCount` method is called on it. Had you run this with `NSZombieEnabled` you would have gotten an error message about sending a message to a deallocated instance.

The reason it returns 0 when called for nil is that methods returning integers will always return 0 when called on a nil object.

Comment: its much convincing...thanks...also program got crashed when i ran with programming tool with NSZombieEnabled enabled...

Comment: to put it succinctly;  messaging a deallocated object yields undefined behavior.  End of story.

Answer (score 2):

Do not depend on `retainCount`. And do not care about this. Lots of things may happen under the hood. You only need to ensure that you have released all the things that you owned. If you are trying to be sure that you are not leaking any memory, then use Instrument, not retainCount in NSLog.

Comment: this answer was expected...well as it is written that after [obj release] reference count gets decremented...so it was just a practical implementation...not to check any LEAK...anyhow thanks...